# Unchecked or unsafe operations error in javac

Tags: java

I am completing a lab assignment for school and get this error when I compile. The program runs fine, bit would like to fix what is causing the error. The program code and the complete error is below. Thanks as always!

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package ie.moguntia.webcrawler;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Cong
 */
public class SaveURL
{

    /**
     * Opens a buffered stream on the url and copies the contents to writer
     */
    public static void saveURL(URL url, Writer writer)
        throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        for (int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read()) {
            writer.write(c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens a buffered stream on the url and copies the contents to OutputStream
     */
    public static void saveURL(URL url, OutputStream os)
        throws IOException {
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1048576];
        int n = is.read(buf);
        while (n != -1) {
            os.write(buf, 0, n);
            n = is.read(buf);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes the contents of the url to a string by calling saveURL with a
     * string writer as argument
     */
    public static String getURL(URL url)
        throws IOException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        saveURL(url, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Writes the contents of the url to a new file by calling saveURL with
     * a file writer as argument
     */
    public static void writeURLtoFile(URL url, String filename)
        throws IOException {
        // FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
        // saveURL(url, writer);
        // writer.close();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        saveURL(url, os);
        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Extract links directly from a URL by calling extractLinks(getURL())
     */
    public static Vector extractLinks(URL url)
        throws IOException {
        return extractLinks(getURL(url));
    }

    public static Map extractLinksWithText(URL url)
        throws IOException {
        return extractLinksWithText(getURL(url));
    }

    /**
     * Extract links from a html page given as a raw and a lower case string
     * In order to avoid the possible double conversion from mixed to lower case
     * a second method is provided, where the conversion is done externally.
     */
    public static Vector extractLinks(String rawPage, String page) {
        int index = 0;
        Vector links = new Vector();
        while ((index = page.indexOf("<a ", index)) != -1)
        {
            if ((index = page.indexOf("href", index)) == -1) break;
            if ((index = page.indexOf("=", index)) == -1) break;
            String remaining = rawPage.substring(++index);
            StringTokenizer st 
                = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\"'>#");
            String strLink = st.nextToken();
            if (! links.contains(strLink)) links.add(strLink);
        }
        return links;
    }


    /**
     * Extract links (key) with link text (value)
     * Note that due to the nature of a Map only one link text is returned per
     * URL, even if a link occurs multiple times with different texts.
     */
    public static Map extractLinksWithText(String rawPage, String page) {
        int index = 0;
        Map links = new HashMap();
        while ((index = page.indexOf("<a ", index)) != -1)
        {
            int tagEnd = page.indexOf(">", index);
            if ((index = page.indexOf("href", index)) == -1) break;
            if ((index = page.indexOf("=", index)) == -1) break;
            int endTag = page.indexOf("</a", index);
            String remaining = rawPage.substring(++index);
            StringTokenizer st 
                = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\"'>#");
            String strLink = st.nextToken();
            String strText = "";
            if (tagEnd != -1 && tagEnd + 1 <= endTag) {
                strText = rawPage.substring(tagEnd + 1, endTag);
            }
            strText = strText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            links.put(strLink, strText);
        }
        return links;

    }

    /**
     * Extract links from a html page given as a String
     * The return value is a vector of strings. This method does neither check
     * the validity of its results nor does it care about html comments, so
     * links that are commented out are also retrieved.
     */
    public static Vector extractLinks(String rawPage) {
        return extractLinks(rawPage, rawPage.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", " "));
    }

    public static Map extractLinksWithText(String rawPage) {
        return extractLinksWithText(rawPage, rawPage.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", " "));
    }

    /**
     * As a standalone program this class is capable of copying a url to a file
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length == 1) {
                URL url = new URL(args[0]);
                System.out.println("Content-Type: " +
                    url.openConnection().getContentType());
//              Vector links = extractLinks(url);
//              for (int n = 0; n < links.size(); n++) {
//                  System.out.println((String) links.elementAt(n));
//              }
                Set links = extractLinksWithText(url).entrySet();
                Iterator it = links.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry en = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    String strLink = (String) en.getKey();
                    String strText = (String) en.getValue();
                    System.out.println(strLink + " \"" + strText + "\" ");
                }
                return;
            } else if (args.length == 2) {
                writeURLtoFile(new URL(args[0]), args[1]);
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("An error occured: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
//          System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        // Display usage information
        // (If the program had done anything sensible, we wouldn't be here.)
        System.err.println("Usage: java SaveURL <url> [<file>]");
        System.err.println("Saves a URL to a file.");
        System.err.println("If no file is given, extracts hyperlinks on url to console.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the raw (i.e. non-generic) forms of several classes that have generic type parameters, including

- Map
- HashMap
- Vector
- Iterator
- Set
- Map.Entry

Use the generic forms of these classes by supplying appropriate type parameters.